# Protobuf-net and StringValue types

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have some protobuf definitions with a lot of google.protobuf.StringValue and google.protobuf.Int32Value types referenced. I am guessing that the first should be just a string in c# but without a default value and the second a int?. Is that right?

This particular event is very large with lots of levels. When the C# class is generated it is generating   Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.StringValue types for which I get a message that there is no serializer. According the Microsoft's documentation that would be a straight string. I understand that all these Value types like StringValue and Int32Value are wrappers to make nullable types.

Answer (score 0):

If you are (tags) talking about protobuf-net: protobuf-net doesn't currently do anything special with those well-known types. It could, in principle, if we added:

- recognition to the code-gen tooling (protogen)
- handling to.the library, to silently add/remove the extra layer of message wrapper

But *today*: those things do not exist. If you think it warrants special treatment, it would be best discussed on GitHub.